# dot2texi: using macros inside labels affects sizing

Tags: tikz-pgf, dot2texi

[image]

The two pictures here are generated by essentially the same code, but the LHS one uses more macros -- so for example the LHS has

```
\newcommand\fouriertransform[1]{\hat{#1}}
\newcommand\applyfn[2]{{#1}(#2)}
\newcommand\sumover[2]{\sum_{#1}#2}
\newcommand\conjugate[1]{\overline{#1}}

1 [label="\sumover{r}{\product{\conjugate{\applyfn{\fouriertransform{g}}{r}}}{\applyfn{\fouriertransform{f}}{r}}}"];
```

where the RHS has

```
1 [label="\sum_{r}{\overline{\hat{g}(r)}\hat{f}(r)}"];
```

For some bizarre reason this is affecting the sizing in the graph... I can't find anything in the dot2tex/dot2texi manuals. I'd be grateful for a fix/explanation.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[autosize]{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\newenvironment{fit}{\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth,max totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}}{\end{adjustbox}}

\newcommand\expectation[2]{\mathbb{E}_{#1}#2}
\newcommand\power[2]{{#1}^{#2}}
\newcommand\add[2]{{#1}+{#2}}
\newcommand\addthree[3]{{#1}+{#2}+{#3}}
\newcommand\subtract[2]{{#1}-{#2}}
\newcommand\negative[1]{-{#1}}
\newcommand\product[2]{{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\productthree[3]{{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand\deltafn[1]{\delta({#1})}
\newcommand\fouriertransform[1]{\hat{#1}}
\newcommand\applyfn[2]{{#1}(#2)}
\newcommand\sumover[2]{\sum_{#1}#2}
\newcommand\conjugate[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand\two{2}

\begin{document}
\begin{fit}
\begin{dot2tex}[twopi,mathmode]
digraph G {
root=0;
overlap=prism;
node [shape="box"];
0 [label="\sumover{r}{\product{\applyfn{\fouriertransform{f}}{r}}{\conjugate{\applyfn{\fouriertransform{g}}{r}}}}"];
1 [label="\sumover{r}{\product{\conjugate{\applyfn{\fouriertransform{g}}{r}}}{\applyfn{\fouriertransform{f}}{r}}}"];
2 [label="\sumover{r}{\product{\expectation{x}{\product{\applyfn{f}{x}}{\power{\omega}{\negative{\product{r}{x}}}}}}{\conjugate{\applyfn{\fouriertransform{g}}{r}}}}"];
3 [label="\sumover{r}{\product{\expectation{x}{\product{\applyfn{\fouriertransform{f}}{x}}{\deltafn{\subtract{x}{r}}}}}{\conjugate{\applyfn{\fouriertransform{g}}{r}}}}"];
4 [label="\sumover{r}{\product{\applyfn{\fouriertransform{f}}{r}}{\conjugate{\expectation{x}{\product{\applyfn{g}{x}}{\power{\omega}{\negative{\product{r}{x}}}}}}}}"];
5 [label="\sumover{r}{\product{\applyfn{\fouriertransform{f}}{r}}{\conjugate{\expectation{x}{\product{\applyfn{\fouriertransform{g}}{x}}{\deltafn{\subtract{x}{r}}}}}}}"];
0 -> 1;
0 -> 2;
0 -> 3;
0 -> 4;
0 -> 5;
}
\end{dot2tex}
\end{fit}
\begin{fit}
\begin{dot2tex}[twopi,mathmode]
digraph G {
root=0;
overlap=prism;
node [shape="box"];
0 [label="\sum_{r}{\overline{\hat{f}(r)}\hat{g}(r)}"];
1 [label="\sum_{r}{\overline{\hat{g}(r)}\hat{f}(r)}"];
2 [label="\sum_{r}{\mathbb{E}_{x}{f(x){\omega}^{{-rx}}}\overline{\hat{g}(r)}}"];
3 [label="\sum_{r}{\mathbb{E}_{x}{\hat{f}(x)\delta(x-r)}\overline{\hat{g}(r)}}"];
4 [label="\sum_{r}{\hat{f}(r)\overline{\mathbb{E}_{x}{g(x){\omega}^{{-rx}}}}}"];
5 [label="\sum_{r}{\hat{f}(r)\overline{\mathbb{E}_{x}{\hat{g}(x)\delta(x-r)}}}"];
0 -> 1;
0 -> 2;
0 -> 3;
0 -> 4;
0 -> 5;
}
\end{dot2tex}
\end{fit}
\end{document}
```

[NB. the adjustbox is just o make everything fit on a page -- commenting it out doesn't fix things.]

Comment: I don't have `dot2tex` installed, but do the `autosize` and `noautosize` options (to `dot2texi`) have any effect?