# Is using this 'fit' environment a good idea?

Tags: graphics, environments, best-practices, fit

I saw [this example document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161865/5640) here on the site defining the following environment:

```
\newenvironment{fit}{%
  \begin{adjustbox}{%
    max width=\textwidth,%
    max totalheight=\textheight,%
    keepaspectratio}%
}{%
  \end{adjustbox}%
}
```

(spaced out for readability). Then the document proceeded to wrap some graphics with this environment (e.g. dot2tex content).

What are the pros and cons of using this kind of environment to wrap graphics? And - what is it redundant with? That is, some environments already allow you to specify one or two maximum dimensions.

**Note:** The question is about the environment in general, not about the content of the linked-to example document.

Comment: what and why do you need to box it?

Comment: @percusse: There's no one specific answer. I just feel this is somewhat redundant with other constructs that I have used over the years.

Comment: Maybe you can link some references (answers that used this environment)?

Comment: Well, scaling any graphics which includes text is officially evil. If you are just including an external image, it seems redundant. (But that's not an environment, of course.)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Done.

Comment: @cfr: see link.

Answer (score 1):

Without context it is impossible to decide whether the code at hand is sensible. The `adjust` box at hand scales an image to either have at maximum a height of `textheight` or a width of `textwidth`. The respective other dimension is scaled appropriately by the same factor using the `keepaspectratio` key. So you can add an image and be sure that it fits within the parameters of your textblock; That can be a minipage, a marginnote…

In that sense it is certainly sensible as it makes sure that no content is lost. If however you have a (pixelated) image, you should adjust the scale yourself so that text is to scale. As for redundancy: Most "include image" commands scale the image while keeping the aspect ratio constant if you provide only one width or height information. If you provide two, the commands scale without keeping the aspect ratio. (Try it yourself with `\includegraphics[width=]` and `\includegraphics[width=, height=]`.) This functionality is what the code implements as limit to height or width.

Depending on the source of the image, it may not carry correct dpi information (dots per inch, a measure for proper scale), which would be necessary for correct scaling. This is certainly true for pictures (take a picture of a text with your camera. How would the camera know which dpi to choose so that the text within the image has the correct size?) but also for many graphics generating programs. I know that I misuse the dpi setting of Inkscape constantly. If you use it properly, you can export from Inkscape to .png (for example at 300 dpi) and then use `\includegraphics{file}` without scaling to have it scaled properly. It is then your responsibility to set the font sizes and scales within Inkscape properly to match the LaTeX ones.

Comment: You can use `keepaspectratio` with an image directly. There is no difference here.